# ng-switch always true

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

I want to hide `ul`s if they are empty:

```
<div class="nav-manage clearfix" ng-app="linksManager">

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="inner-list.html">

        <li ng-repeat='link in link.submenu'>
            <a href="{{link.url}}">{{link.text}}</a>
            <div ng-switch on="link.submenu">
                <ul class="sortable" ng-include="'inner-list.html'">
            </div>
        </li>

    </script>

    <div class="links-arrange" ng-controller="linksRarrange">
        <ul class="sortable">
            <li ng-repeat="link in links">
                    <a href="{{link.url}}">{{link.text}}</a>
                    <div ng-switch on="link.submenu">
                        <ul class="sortable" ng-include="'inner-list.html'"></ul>
                    </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

But they are not hidden regardless of the content in the `ng-switch on`

This is the data structure:

```
var linksData = [
    {
        text: 'Menu Item 1',
        url: '#'
    }, {
        text: 'Menu Item 2',
        url: '#',
        submenu: [
            {
                text: 'Sub-menu Item 3',
                url: '#'
            }, {
                text: 'Sub-menu Item 4',
                url: '#',
                submenu: // etc ...
];
```

Comment: "ng-switch on" is not used on its own.. You will have to have a when clause there..an "ng-switch-when" needs to be below it or it wont work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-switch` works as ...well... a javascript `switch`, you need to use `ng-switch on` along with `ng-switch-when` for it to work (check the example [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch)). However, in this case, `ng-switch` doesn't seem to be a good solution, what you need is something like [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.com/) `ui-if` directive (src code [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/directives/if/if.js)):

> **What?** Remove elements from the DOM completely instead of just hiding
>   it.
>
> **Why?** In situations where DOM traversal matters (such as the CSS
>   selectors :first-child, :last-child and :nth()-child), simply hiding
>   elements is not enough.

Example:

```
<div ui-if="link.submenu">
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/fBLTd/

Comment: thanx! this is exactly what I needed! only one question: do I have to use it in a wrapper element or can I put it inside the element I want to hide?

Comment: You can put it directly on the element you want to hide.